Need to identify the movie by photo/ clip
I have tried searching google by photo and searching movie sites, but couldn't find the movie. A small clip (ignore the audio) can be found here.
Few images are below,



Does anybody know the film name?

can downvoter add a comment?

Image ID questions are off-topic for Movie and TV

That's Sylvester Stallone. You can go from there.

any place you know to get a help from? I tried google image search

The movie is Taxi 3 (2003).

Taxi is a 1998 French action-comedy film starring Samy Naceri,
  Frédéric Diefenthal and Marion Cotillard, written by Luc Besson and
  directed by Gérard Pirès.

Source
and is the third film of the Taxi film series as mentioned in the comments.
The clip you have shared is a popular comedy clip video in you tube.

Sylvester Stallone had a cameo at the beginning of the film as a taxi
  passenger with his voice dubbed as he cannot speak French.

The opening scene of the movie can be found here: 


Source

Thank you for the detailed answer

I dint see what was in the comments actually. Went straight to the link you shared.:)
